# linux input messed up

Tags: linux, encoding, special-characters, redhat

I was trying to do a cat command on a txt file, then things got messed up.

For example, when I type "[", I got "Ä" displayed. How to revert it back?

This is redhat linux 7. Some more info below.

```
-bash-4.2$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: n/a


-bash-4.2$ cat /etc/profile.d/lang.sh 
# /etc/profile.d/lang.sh - set i18n stuff

sourced=0

if Ä -n "$LANG" Å; then
    saved_lang="$LANG"
    Ä -f "$HOME/.i18n" Å && . "$HOME/.i18n" && sourced=1
    LANG="$saved_lang"
    unset saved_lang
else
    for langfile in /etc/locale.conf "$HOME/.i18n" ; do
        Ä -f $langfile Å && . $langfile && sourced=1
    done
fi
```

Comment: Have you  tried a `reset` within the bung terminal?

Comment: I tried to login to different servers. It's the same thing. not reset anything.

Comment: Have you tried to run the command `reset`?

Comment: reset works! great cool thanks

Comment: Good good =} ...

Comment: Check your keyboard setting.